# Tag merge request: [antd] and [ant-design]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I just created [antd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antd) and [ant-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant-design). I first created `ant-design`, but after [discussing in the project repository on GitHub](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/4353#issuecomment-269187071) the author prefers to use [antd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antd). I tagged now all questions with both tags, preparing for a merge.

[ant-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant-design) should be merged into [antd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antd), i.e. keeping `antd`.

I would grateful if some moderator (♦) could help on this.